# addProximityAlert doesn't work (neither does requestLocationUpdates) - Android

Tags: android, gps, android-sensors

I'm trying to get and update when the phone gets near a location.
I've both tried using addProximityAlert and requestLocationUpdates

```
    LocationManager lm =(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation("gps");
    Intent intent = new Intent("eu.mauriziopz.gps.ProximityAlert");
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    lm.addProximityAlert(12, 12, 100, 1000000, pIntent);
```

This one never fires the intent (which I know works since I can fire it up manually).
I tried using a listener but it gets executed only once. No matter how many times I update the gps it never gets called again

```
    ProximityListener pl = new ProximityListener();
    lm. requestLocationUpdates("gps", 2000, 10, pl);
```

this is the code of the activity (called in the first case)

```
public class ProximityAlert extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("intent", "Hi");
    finish();
}
```

This is the Listener

```
public class ProximityListener implements LocationListener {
String DEBUG_TAG = "ProximityListener";
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, location.toString());

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is how you define you Intent / PendingIntent. There are two ways to start an Activity using an Intent, and the code you've included looks like a cross between the two.

The standard way of starting an Activity is to use the Intent constructor that takes the current context and the Activity's class and use the `getActivity` method on `PendingIntent` to create the PendingIntent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProximityAlert.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Alternatively, you can add an `IntentReceiver` to your Activity in the Manifest, with an IntentFilter that listens for a particular action (like "eu.mauriziopz.gps.ProximityAlert"). However, in that case you need to use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` to create the PendingIntent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("eu.mauriziopz.gps.ProximityAlert");
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

In all cases you need to make sure you've got the correct permissions for location-based services defined in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

---

Also, rather than using the string "gps", you might consider using the static constant `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.sccp.fourgdummy.REQUEST_DFGS");
intent.putExtra("launch_tab", "otp");
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

this is important : `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Answer (score 1):

The API defines the parameters of `addProximityAlert` to be lat, long, radius, expiration, intent. Have you tried setting the expiration to `-1` rather than `100000`

<strike>`lm.addProximityAlert(12, 12, 100, 1000000, pIntent);`</strike>

```
lm.addProximityAlert(12, 12, 100, -1, pIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should terminate the Activity already in the onCreate method (by calling finish()).

Comment: that was just a debug activity and I was interested in seeing if it writes on the Log, so finishing the activity doesn't change much.
But thanks for the answer